# how to prevent R from showing exp and log values inf and zero

Tags: r, matrix, probability-density, infinity, log-likelihood

I am going to calculate matrix normal densities to use them in loglikelihood formula.
in my calculations, I need to calculate exponential of large numbers ( tens of million ). I realized, R gives back infinity for exp(i), when i >=710. 
is there anyway I can force R manually not to show infinity, or its log not to be 0 accordingly?

thanks for correcting my typo

Comment: Typo: it's `exp(i)` when i >= 710 that gives infinity, not `log`.

Answer (score 3):

You should know that the max double number in R is `.Machine$double.xmax`. If you have numbers great than this, it will definitely give you `Inf`

```
> log(.Machine$double.xmax)  
[1] 709.7827
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I m very new to both statistics and R. I did not know that. I just tried different numbers in a loop to find that 710 value. So I assume you mean there is no way to ask R not to show infinity for exp of numbers greater that 710. is there any hint or trick to apply when I need to compare exp of numbers much larger than 710?

Comment: @Mathica Maybe you can try package `gmp` for super large integers. Maybe others know more options than me.

Comment: `library(Brobdingnag); exp(as.brob(710))`. See the [package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Brobdingnag) vignette.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Good option! Thanks. I guess you should write it as an answer and I will upvote for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is also contributed package [Brobdingnag](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Brobdingnag) that can handle numbers much bigger than `exp(710)`.

```
library(Brobdingnag)

exp(as.brob(710))
#[1] +exp(710)

exp(as.brob(10^seq(100, 310, by = 5)))
# [1] +exp(1e+100) +exp(1e+105) +exp(1e+110) +exp(1e+115) +exp(1e+120)
# [6] +exp(1e+125) +exp(1e+130) +exp(1e+135) +exp(1e+140) +exp(1e+145)
#[11] +exp(1e+150) +exp(1e+155) +exp(1e+160) +exp(1e+165) +exp(1e+170)
#[16] +exp(1e+175) +exp(1e+180) +exp(1e+185) +exp(1e+190) +exp(1e+195)
#[21] +exp(1e+200) +exp(1e+205) +exp(1e+210) +exp(1e+215) +exp(1e+220)
#[26] +exp(1e+225) +exp(1e+230) +exp(1e+235) +exp(1e+240) +exp(1e+245)
#[31] +exp(1e+250) +exp(1e+255) +exp(1e+260) +exp(1e+265) +exp(1e+270)
#[36] +exp(1e+275) +exp(1e+280) +exp(1e+285) +exp(1e+290) +exp(1e+295)
#[41] +exp(1e+300) +exp(1e+305) +exp(Inf)
```

And `10^305` is much bigger than `710`. See the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Brobdingnag/vignettes/brobpaper.pdf).

Comment: wonderful! I wrote a function in which I used exp(as.bob()) as you nicely explained. it s just when I use my function, I get the error : incompatible types (from S4 to double) in subassignment type fix. I realized type of exp(as.prob()) is S4. how can exp(as.brob()) return just a double class value. ( as.double(exp(as.brob())) gives inf again of course.