# how to do algebraic calculations with class S4 outputs in r , as.bob()

Tags: r, function, error-handling, r-s4, exp

I asked a question here :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68275613/how-to-prevent-r-from-showing-exp-and-log-values-inf-and-zero)

from there I learnt about as.brob() function.
 it helps me avoid getting infinity when raising e to a very large number. ( I am going to use exp(as.brob()) in a function I wrote in my coded .
now my question is, since I am going to call my function and give it inputs and get a real number output, it gives me an S4 class error. 
how can I get a real value output from exp(as.brob))? 

 below is matrix normal density function:

```
   dMNorm <- function(Y, Mu, Sigma, Psi, Sigma.inv = NULL, Psi.inv = NULL, Sigma.det = NULL, Psi.det = NULL){   
  if (is.null(Sigma.inv)) Sigma.inv <- solve(Sigma)   
  if (is.null(Psi.inv)) Psi.inv <- solve(Psi)   
  if (is.null(Sigma.det)) Sigma.det <- det(Sigma)     
  if (is.null(Psi.det)) Psi.det <- det(Psi)    
  p <- dim(Y)[1] 
  Tt <- dim(Y)[2]     
  den <- ((2 * pi)^((-1)* p * Tt / 2)) * (Sigma.det^((-1)* Tt / 2)) * (Psi.det^((-1)* p / 2)) *
  exp(-1 / 2 * sum(diag(Sigma.inv %*% (Y - Mu) %*% Psi.inv %*% t(Y - Mu)))***)

#cat("dens", den , "\n")
return(den)
}
```

line 9 of the function above is where I get really small ( inverse of a really big number ) . for which I was guided to use as.brob(), so I changed this part to

```
1/exp(as.brob(1 / 2 * sum(diag(Sigma.inv %*% (Y - Mu) %*% Psi.inv %*% t(Y - Mu))))***)
```

but when I want to use my function dMNorm(), I get :

**Error in Phi.vector[i] I would appreciate any helo or hint with this.
ps, needless to mention dmatrixnorm() from LaplacesDemon package does not work here.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Even if you calculate this extremely small number, what would you do with it? Usually, one would just calculate the log of the density instead.

Comment: If you really need this (I doubt that), use the Rmpfr package.

Comment: @Roland, because when I use den<- log(((2 * pi)^((-1)* p * Tt / 2)) * (Sigma.det^((-1)* Tt / 2)) * (Psi.det^((-1)* p / 2)) *
  exp(-1 / 2 * sum(diag(Sigma.inv %*% (Y - Mu) %*% Psi.inv %*% t(Y - Mu)))***)), I still get most of my density values equal zero. I do not know of any other way, but I was thinking maybe forcing R to use the ACTUAL values, no matter how big or small they are, helps me with not getting zero densities.

Comment: Simplify that expression using the laws of logarithms.